# Drawing an edge starting at an edge and ending at a node using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to replicate this diagram using LaTeX/tikz:
[image]

This is what I have so far, however I'm not sure how to draw an edge to a new node G from the edge connecting nodes A and B:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [sibling distance=12em,level distance=6em,
    every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,align=center}]
    
    \node{A}
        child{node{B}
            child{node{C}
                child{node{E}}}
            child{node{D}
                child{node{F}}}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [sibling distance=12em,level distance=6em,
    every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em,rounded corners,
        align=center}]
    
    \node (A) {A}
        child{node{B}
            child{node{C}
                child{node{E}}}
            child{node{D}
                child{node{F}}}};
    \path (A) -- node[right=6em] (G){G} (A-1) (G) edge (G-|A);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]